# Unable to retrieve the access token. Status: 401ccess token on twitter android

Tags: android

I've download source from http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Its perfectely worked on past month.

when i check now., i can't able to use twitter. Its throws error.

```
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Unable to retrieve the access token. Status: 401
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.util.OAuthConsumer.getAccessToken(OAuthConsumer.java:251)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth1.verifyResponse(OAuth1.java:96)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth1.verifyResponse(OAuth1.java:106)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.TwitterImpl.doVerifyResponse(TwitterImpl.java:174)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.TwitterImpl.verifyResponse(TwitterImpl.java:165)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager.connect(SocialAuthManager.java:183)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog$SocialAuthWebViewClient$1.run(SocialAuthDialog.java:201)
04-06 14:30:12.130: W/System.err(1595):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

I've checked , callback url(https://www.google.co.in/), and consumer key, and permission(Read ,write 
and direct message)

now i can't access the twitter.

What is the problem? Why can't access the token?

Comment: hi ganesh please check the new jar

Comment: @vineet hi., the new jar working to get user profile only. when i get friends list, its throws error.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for feedback  will check and let you know soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Hi, have a look at https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=46, it appears to be the same issue.

Twitter made some changes very recently that aren't yet reflected in the socialauth-android library, but the socialauth-android people have provided a new library jar (see issue comments).